# Mapbox SDK offline map Download

Tags: ios, mapbox, offline-caching

I'am trying to download offline map using Mapbox SDK and its succesfully downloaded in basic mapstyle(i.e [NSURL URLWithString:@"mapbox://styles/mapbox/basic-v9"]). but when am try to download satellite style(i.e [MGLStyle satelliteStreetsStyleURLWithVersion:9]) its not downloading as expected.

i.e  if i use zoom scale as 0 - maxZoomlevel(20) of map, it throws offlinePackDidReceiveMaximumAllowedMapboxTiles exceeded error.

and if i use small zoom range its 5 - 10 its download succesfully but map shows white screen.

Does anyone tried to download offline in satellite mode ? 
Is it possible to change mapbox tile limit to a greater value ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are hitting the [tile limit](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mobile-offline/#tile-ceiling--limits), which is 6000 tiles. The limit can be raised with an enterprise plan. The number of tiles required by a region increases with the zoom level. You've already found the workaround, which is to adjust the minimum and maximum zoom for the offline region. You can use this [tile count estimator](https://www.mapbox.com/labs/offline-estimator/) to estimate the size of your offline region.